# .NET events special methods (add/remove/raise/other)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, events, clr

I was wondering about the [`EventInfo.GetRaiseMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.eventinfo.getraisemethod.aspx) and [`EventInfo.GetOtherMethods`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.eventinfo.getothermethods.aspx) methods. Apparently, the CLR supports 4 kinds of methods associated with events: add, remove, raise, and "others". But events created in C# only have *add* and *remove*... I assumed that *raise* was used in VB, since you have to specify a `RaiseEvent` method when you declare a custom event, but apparently it's not the case: `GetRaiseMethod` always returns null.

So, does anyone know:

- what's the point in having a *raise* method associated with an event if it's never used? Is there a specific MSIL instruction to raise an event using this method? (I couln't find anything like it in the opcodes)
- what are the "other" methods returned (well, *not* returned actually) by `GetOtherMethods`? What's are they supposed to do?
- are there types in the BCL that implement those special methods?

Comment: *"Is there a specific MSIL instruction to raise an event using this method?"* Nope. Just like there's no CIL instruction to set a property, get a property, add a handler, or remove a handler. They are all done with call/callvirt. (And yes, it's call CIL, not MSIL.)

Comment: Well, it *was* called MSIL, but it's now called CIL... I have to get used to that ;)

Comment: This question confused me in the past, and at last I thought it's used for VB, you have tried that it still returns null in VB?

Comment: @Danny, yes, it also returns null for events created in VB (custom events and normal field-like events)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, raise isn't used much, and I've practically never seen it used. C++/CLI is pretty much the only language I know that make it easy to declare a raise method. See this code for example:

```
using namespace System;

ref class Foo {

private:
    Action ^bar;

public:
    event Action ^Bar {
        void add (Action ^action)
        {
            Console::WriteLine ("add");
            bar += action;
        }

        void remove (Action ^action)
        {
            Console::WriteLine ("remove");
            bar -= action;
        }

        void raise ()
        {
            Console::WriteLine ("raise");

            if (!bar)
                return;

            Console::WriteLine ("raise for real");
            bar->Invoke ();
        }
    };
};

void hello ()
{
    Console::WriteLine ("hello");
}

void main ()
{
    Foo ^foo = gcnew Foo ();
    foo->Bar ();

    foo->Bar += gcnew Action (&hello);

    foo->Bar ();
}
```

Which, when being run, naturally outputs:

```
C:\tmp>test
raise
add
raise
raise for real
hello
```

To answer your question, there's no opcode to invoke an event, the compiler will just emit a call to the raise method:

```
  IL_0020:  ldloc.0
  IL_0021:  call       instance void Foo::raise_Bar()
```

Just like it emits a call to add_Bar.

It's also worth nothing that as C# allows you to invoke an event exclusively in the scope of the type which declares the member event, you can't get C# code to call that raise method. So no, you won't find such a method exposed in the BCL.

As for the `.other` kind of methods, I've never seen any attached to an event. And I only [saw them used once for properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840229/the-curiosity-of-the-let-property-method), and neither the book «Inside IL assembler» nor «The CLI annotated standard» give any information about them. But basically, they allow you to attach methods to a property or to a event to bind them semantically. They're neither a `addon`, nor a `removeon`, nor a `raise` method, but they would be part of the event, should a language need to express that. In the meantime, the only way to emit one is to use ilasm.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting answer! Perhaps if you declare a "foo" method in the event, it will appear in .other methods?

Comment: No it won't, in Cpp/CLI, only add, remove, and raise methods are allowed.

Comment: The only place I've ever seen .other implemented in an IL sample (not real code) is in Serge Lidin's book (Expert .Net 2.0 IL Assembler) which starts on page 318.  The method he uses with the .other is called HasSubscribers and returns a bool.  The sample IL that uses the event doesn't show any usage of the .other method though but wouldn't be too hard to put together.  The thing is, with IL those are just other methods that are associated with an .event ... like with the .fire method - c# and vb don't define the .fire method for the events. (they don't associate that method with the event)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, C# can use the add/remove overloads for registering event handlers. `EventInfo` is the `System.Reflection` metadata that is used when parsing a class' signature; the `RaiseEvent` method in Visual Basic is not necessarily the same method as this one, as reflection creates a way for you to dynamically invoke an event or add an event handler. `RaiseEvent` is similar to calling the event in C# like a method.

(This is a partial answer, as there are questions in your post I don't know the answer too.)