# Why would one declare both a Let and Set property accessor in VB6

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

In an older project I found a property declaration in a class module which looks like the following...

```
Public Property Get DrawObject() As Object
    Set DrawObject = m_obj
End Property
Public Property Let DrawObject(obj As Object)
    Set m_obj = obj
    Draw
End Property
Public Property Set DrawObject(obj As Object)
    Set m_obj = obj
    Draw
End Property
```

I would like to know why the `DrawObject` property has both a `Let` and `Set` accessor defined; what could be the purpose of such a declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason would be to allow/support both assignment syntaxes:

```
set instance.DrawObject = obj
```

and

```
instance.DrawObject = obj
```

Comment: I see; feels a bit odd to me... Found another good explanation about the difference of `Let` and `Set`; just adding the link for completeness: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042379/in-vb6-what-is-the-difference-between-property-set-and-property-let

Comment: The link is important since it explains what the two syntaxes mean.