# Redeclaring a variable using `let` results in “Uncaught SyntaxError: redeclaration of let …”

Tags: javascript, variables, variable-declaration

I have code like this:

```js
let accessAllowed;

accessAllowed = (2>18) ? true : false;
alert(accessAllowed);
```

However when I use this:

```js
let accessAllowed;
let accessAllowed = (2>18) ? true : false;

alert(accessAllowed);
```

It results is an error and none of the JavaScript works.

Being a newbie to JS, I’m unsure if this is a feature of `let`. I couldn’t find anything about this elsewhere.

Comment: you're redeclaring by using let the second time

Comment: You know that `(2>18) ? true : false;  ` is the same as `(2>18)` ?

Answer (score 10):

You cannot use `let` to redeclare a variable, whereas you can with `var`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

> Redeclaring the same variable within the same function or block scope raises a SyntaxError.

`let` has different (arguably more useful) scoping rules than `var` to help prevent many types of bugs caused by `var`'s quirks which don't exist in other languages but which must be retained in JavaScript for backwards compatibility with scripts written decades ago.

#### Sidenote on `let`:

Note that many programming languages have the `let` keyword and often use it for declaring variables and constants - however note that each language's use of `let` has very different behavior, so do not expect `let` in JavaScript to behave like `let` in Swift, for example.

- JavaScript: `let` - [declares a variable whose scope is limited to the enclosing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), as opposed to `var` which uses either the global scope or the function scope (and understanding how `var` chooses between the two is not easy for beginners to understand). Because redeclaring a variable in the same scope is a meaningless operation that is probably done in-error it will give you a compiler error, whereas redeclaring with `var` is valid inside a closure.
- Swift: `let` - [declares a constant](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html). Note that a "constant" is not just a literal value, but also includes complex objects that are immutable.
- Rust: `let` - [Introduces a variable binding](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/variable-bindings.html). Essentially the same thing as `let` in JavaScript except by default values are immutable (like in Swift). Use `let mut` to declare a mutable variable.
- C#: `let` [is a Linq keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause) shorthand for `Select` and `SelectMany`.
- VBScript, VBA and VB6: `Let` is a keyword that declares a class [property](https://www.vbsedit.com/html/23a9ca52-91c1-4257-a090-fdb397380ece.asp) [setter for a value-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042379/in-vb6-what-is-the-difference-between-property-set-and-property-let) (i.e. not object-types).

Answer (score 1):

Let cannot be re-declared in the same scope ( What you are doing is re-declaring, Rather you should not use the 'let' keyword in the 2nd line and would just reassign ).