# Invalid use of property with type ListObject

Tags: excel, vba, properties

I am working on a simple UserForm in Excel with VBA and the aim is to pass a Table (Therefore a ListObject) to the UserForm so that it can handle changes and has all the data required to do the tasks I want.

Right now I have two properties, one of type String which contains an operation type and the other is said Table.

As of now, the UserForm code is the following:

```
Private msOperationType As String
Private msDataTable As ListObject

Property Let OperationType(sText As String)
    msOperationType = sText
    NewOperationTitle.Caption = "New operation: " & sText
    InformationLabel.Caption = "Fill out all the information regarding the " & sText & " operation"
End Property

Property Let DataTable(sDataTable As ListObject)
    msDataTable = sDataTable
End Property

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'Code here will do things
End Sub
```

In my module, I have the following code:

```
Dim AddOperationForm As UserForm1
Set AddOperationForm = New UserForm1
AddOperationForm.OperationType = "Add"
AddOperationForm.DataTable = Worksheets(14).ListObjects("Operations")
AddOperationForm.Show
```

However, when I run the code (launched from a button in a sheet), I get a `Compile Error: Invalid use of property` and the `Property Let DataTable(sDataTable As ListObject)` gets highlighted but this doesn't help me understand why there is an issue with my code. The equivalent code for a String for OperationType works fine so I'm unsure how I can fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using property set instead of property let. property let should only be used for value types while object types should use property set.

See also [In VB6 what is the difference between Property Set and Property Let?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042379/in-vb6-what-is-the-difference-between-property-set-and-property-let)

Comment: You read my mind. I was about to ask what differences there are between the two. Thanks a lot!

Comment: :-) VBA is peculiar to say the least. I used to love VBA but it is quickly outgrown like a plant in a small pot. I really advise you to move to Python. I have run into all sorts of difficulties with VBA, including unexplained  Excel crashes, and I say Excel not the VBA script crashing. Wish you the best in your endeavors.

Comment: Would you happen to know why you can only add a single Set statement in a Property Set function ?

Comment: Don't forget to mark as answered and even upvote.

Comment: What do you mean by "single set statement for a property"? Could you illustrate by some code?

Comment: Simply put, any code I write after the `Set msDataTable = sDataTable` generates the invalid use of property warning

Comment: The next statement you are putting must have a problem of its own. What is this statement, indicating the type of variables involved. You can update your question by adding the offending code.

Comment: Indeed, small typo caused the whole ordeal. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: :-) happy programming!